# Does Spring Integration's JDBC inbound channel adapter poll new records added the table?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have written jdbcinboud channel adapter as below. I am using update query. however it is not working. The query retrieves two rows, but update statement does not set the `accType` of these two rows to 'P'.
Please advise

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="jdbcInbound"
          channel="channel"
          data-source="dataSource"
          query="SELECT id, acct_nam FROM Accounts where accType ='N'"       
          update="update Accounts set accType='P' where ID in (:id)        
          row-mapper="AccountRowMapper"
          max-rows-per-poll="100">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does call that `query="SELECT * FROM Accounts"` on every polling cycle and pulls `100` rows and probably in your case those are only first `100` since there is no other criteria to filter out.

In general it is bad practice to do a common `SELECT` without any `WHERE`.

See there is an `update` atribute to perform against just pulled rows. Your `SELECT` must be adjusted with a `WHERE` to take only those rows which have not been updated before.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-inbound-channel-adapter

Comment: Thanks Artem. I tried to use update. however  Status is not updated to 'P' .  I have updated the code above with update. Please advise

Comment: Not sure. Looks like you have missed to save your edit for the question. I don't see an updated code.

Comment: All looks good. Although it is not clear why do you talk about ` Status` since your filter and update are against `accType`...

Comment: typed Status by mistake...updated it to accType. Can you please clarify for me-  DOes jdbc inbound channel adapter fires query  and gets the entire result set on every poll ? If there are millions of records with accType = 'N', will those all be fetched on every poll ?

Comment: You said it yourself `max-rows-per-poll="100"`. So, no more than 100 per SELECT. As long as you update those out from `accType ='N'` they become invisible for `SELECT` and the next poll will fetch other 100.