# How to make Spring Integrations jdbc inbound channel adapter to poll new data?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-jdbc

I have written jdbc inbound adapter as below

```
int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="jdbcInbound"
                                      channel="channel"
                                      data-source="dataSource"
                                      query="SELECT * FROM Trade"
                                      row-mapper="TradeRowMapper"
                                      max-rows-per-poll="100">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="60000" time-unit="SECONDS"/>
    </int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

This works fine.
But if new records are added to the Trade table say throughout the day, new records are not picked up. What changes do I need to make for it poll new data as well. This adapter is going to keep running for 5 business days monday-friday - and it should read all new records as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered in the [reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-inbound-channel-adapter):

> [...] the adapter also has an UPDATE statement that marks the records as processed so that they do not show up in the next poll.

There is also a snippet showing how to use it:

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter query="select * from item where status=2"
    channel="target" data-source="dataSource"
    update="update item set status=10 where id in (:id)" />
```

Comment: See also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75381609/does-spring-integrations-jdbc-inbound-channel-adapter-poll-new-records-added-th. It looks like you both are from the same team since your questions are similar.